# How can we get traffic update using google map api all location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

Hi i am trying to show traffic on google map.Its working fine but it gives info for only some selected city's...how can i get traffic for all City's or the selected coordinates . Is there is any another option for showing traffic please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're speaking about [traffic layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic), it is only available for some cities supported by Google.

You can take a look to [this spreadsheet](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html) (column `traffic`) to see if your country is supported or not.

Comment: ya i know that...is there is any other option or any idea how to create traffic on maps...actually i have traffic details according to the get coordinates is there any option to  show it on map

Comment: What do you mean by "create traffic" ? Do you want to simulate traffic or get real-time traffic data ?

Comment: real time traffic data